# PhpStorm understanding of magic methods

Tags: php, phpstorm

Our classes don't have explictic `getPropertyName()` and `setPropertyName()` methods. Instead we're using trait, which implements combination of magic `__get()`, `__set()` and `__call()` methods, so, we can have following as result:

```
class Device {
use ModelAttributes;

/**
 * @var \string
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var \string
 */
protected $subtitle;

}

$device = new Device();
$device->setTitle('PC');
$device->getTitle();
```

But the problem is, that now PhpStorm can't recognize and highlights these methods.

I know, that I can add `@method string getTitle()` into class phpDoc, but this will mean, taht I again need to add all get-ers and set-ers, but in form of phpDoc commetns, and I want to avoid this.

It would be really great, if I could do something like:

```
/**
 * @var \string
 * @get
 * @set
 */
protected $title;
```

Does someone have experience with such situation?

Comment: You can relax corresponding inspection -- it will not help with making those methods appearing in code completion popup (you need to list them explicitly via PHPDoc to make this available there), but IDE will stop complaining for unknown methods.

Comment: @LazyOne, yes, that might help, but still not perfect solution...

Comment: +1, what have you found since this question ?

Comment: @Niloct after half of a year we realized, that we get less benefits from this trait, than pain, and switched to getProperty() and setProperty() approach. This gives a benefit of typeCasting for set-ers, which was hardly possible with trait. Also phpStorm allows to generate get() and set() method for each property, so we are using it as well.